# Toggle function in javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to write a simple button control in javascript that will self encpsulate toggle functionality so every time it works it changes the show or hide of an element.
I thought this could be easy but I'm not able to get it to work.

```
simplify: function(){
    aRemoveButtons[t].show();

    //next time 
    aRemoveButtons[t].hide();
}
```

I tried to set a variable and then do a !variable on it but I couldn't check for its existance as it was a boolean and false was seen to be the same as undefined.

Comment: what is t? because you have 0 params showing on your function, also, you know this function is already easily available if you add jQuery to yourstuff?

Comment: Depending on what this is for, there may already be a function in jQuery that can do this for you: `aRemoveButtons[t].toggle();` I assume you're using jQuery because of the `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Comment: "I need a three line function". "Install jQuery! It can do it in one after loading an 80k lib!"

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery? It has a built-in toggle-Method: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

Comment: not this time round, also I think the toggle works in conjunction to a view.

Comment: no I'm using sencha  I fixed it now by setting the state on the button itself.Thanks for all your help

Comment: if you already solved the problem then can you mark the closest answer as accepted so people will know that you don't need help for this problem anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
function toggle(elementID) {
    var target1 = document.getElementById(elementID); // get the element
    if (target1.style.display == 'none') { // check current state
        target1.style.display = 'block'; // show
    } else {
        target1.style.display = 'none';  // hide
    }
}​
```

usage :

```
<div id="something" style="display:none;"></div>

toggle('something');
```

Comment: I wanted the javascript function itself to keep the state, yes I may have to do something like this. I'm using sencha framework.

Comment: @landed I have added the sencha tag - hope you get a better response

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.override(Ext.Element, {
    toggle : function()
    {
        // check current state of visibility
        var mode = this.getVisibilityMode();
        var hideClass = '';

        switch (mode) {
            case Ext.Element.prototype.VISIBILITY:
                    hideClass = 'x-hidden-visibility';
                break;
            case Ext.Element.prototype.DISPLAY:
                    hideClass = ''x-hidden-display';
                break;
            case Ext.Element.prototype.OFFSETS:
                    hideClass = 'x-hidden-offsets';
                break;
        }

        // default should be visible
        var visible = true;
            // if class exists then the element is hidden
        if(this.hasCls(hideClass)) {
            visible = false;
        }

        this.setVisible(!visible);
    }
});
```